# NavigationView not full height with google map

Tags: android, drawerlayout, navigationview

[image]

As you guys can see from the pic above (blue area at the bottom screen), the navigation view doesn't fill all parent's height when using with google map, there's a extra space at the bottom of the screen. What could be the reason?

Please help me:)

Here is my xml code :

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
android:background="@color/white"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <LinearLayout
  android:id="@+id/content_frame"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical">
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
   android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
   android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
   android:elevation="4dp"
   android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
   app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/lastupdate"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:textColor="@color/material_red_a400"/>


    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>

 <!-- The navigation drawer -->
   <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
     android:id="@+id/navigation"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:layout_gravity="start"
     app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
     app:menu="@menu/my_navigation_items"
     android:background="@color/white"
     app:itemBackground="@drawable/menu_item_ripple">

   </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

 </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change the width of the NavigationView programatically via DrawerLayout.LayoutParams

```
mNavigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nv_navigation);
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
DrawerLayout.LayoutParams params = (DrawerLayout.LayoutParams) mNavigationView.getLayoutParams();
params.width = metrics.widthPixels;
mNavigationView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use parameter `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"`.

> The default behavior of the android:fitsSystemWindows="true" attribute
>   gives you: it sets the padding of the View to ensure the contents
>   don’t overlay the system windows.

To understand what `fitsSystemWindows`please read the this [article](https://medium.com/google-developers/why-would-i-want-to-fitssystemwindows-4e26d9ce1eec).

Comment: Please explain your answer.